# Move/copy document set to another library in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, document-set

I would like to automatically copy or move document sets with specific properties to another library (SharePoint Online).
I've tried the following methods in SharePoint Designer workflows:

- Workflow action Copy Document -> HTTP NotFound
- Workflow action Copy Item -> "Make sure the source and destination lists have the same columns and column settings"
- REST call: file/copyTo -> NotFound

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the Manage content and Structure option?

1. Site settings
2. Site Administration
3. Manage content and structure
4. Navigate to the folder you wish to move
5. Select tick box and use the actions drop down
6. Select the move option and then select the location to move to.

If this doesn't work and you have the option of using third party software, ShareGate is a very useful product for migrations and copying SharePoint content.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm afraid it's not suitable in this case as I want it to be an automatic process. Document sets should be moved whenever the property get a certain value.

Answer (score 1):

I think OOB SharePoint does not provide this feature, I would advise you to consider to use the third-party tool [Plumsail Actions Pack](https://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/).

Please check-out the following article to know more:

[Copy document-set to another library cross-site](https://plumsail.com/docs/workflow-actions-pack/how-to/Copy%20document%20set%20to%20another%20library.html)

PS: I want to notice that this is paid product and I'm a member of the developer's team.